# Serializing scala map with gson returns "key" with every key

Tags: json, scala, gson

New to scala and tried searching for this but couldn't find a solution for it. I've a scala map like shown below:

```
val myMap = Map("foo" -> "baz")
```

I want to serialize this using Gson library and here's what I am doing:

```
val json = new Gson()
val serializedMap = json.ToJson(myMap)
```

When I print the `serializedMap` I get
`"{"key1":"foo", "value1":"baz"}"` but I was expecting `"{"foo": "baz"}"`

What am I missing?

Comment: As Gson is a Java lib, thus, as you can see, it may lack support for some common Scala types, not only for Map. It may be reasonable to look for a different json lib, if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gson is a Java library, so it has no special treatment of Scala collections. What you are seeing there is probably some internal instance variables it found through reflection. If you want to use Gson, you will probably need to convert everything to Java collections:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
myMap.asJava
```

But you may wish to look at Scala-specific json libraries also. There are plenty of good ones.